# How to have an ImageView appear on multiple pages while scrolling a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

It should look something like this:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxUOv.png

I'm thinking that I may need to have it on the Activity controlled by the ViewPager. Is there a better way?

EDIT: So I've made a version with a HorizontalScrollView in front of the ViewPager, but this has the problem of capturing scrolls. Code:

```
void initOverlayAnimator() {
    ViewTreeObserver observer = mViewPager.getViewTreeObserver();
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            mOverlayAnimator.setScreenWidth(mViewPager.getWidth());
            mViewPager.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                    this);
        }
    });

    scrollImg.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()

    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    scrollImg.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    scrollImg.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

    mOverlayAnimator.addView(imgIntroArrow, 3, 2);
}
```

Also tried to bypass from XML, no luck:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollImg"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:contextClickable="false"
        android:longClickable="false">
```

So the question remains, is there a better way, or what can I do about the scroll not passing the touch event?

Comment: you could just use a scrollview and put it above an image.

Comment: @EluciusFTW updated with code.

Comment: @NicolasTyler That's what I was thinking based on some answers on SO about larger-than-screen images, so that is what I tried. New problem above.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is set a back-view for the view pager's container frame, and have it set a as an image and move that image left or right when the view pager is scrolled

Comment: Only problem with this solution is: My ViewPager already has a background, so that there is a parallax background effect too. The arrow needs to go in front of it, and only appear on page 2 and 3, scrolling accordingly. This movement is what the OverlayAnimator handles.

Comment: Also It would seem so much more logical and easier if I could just stop the ScrollView from intercepting scroll events. Read several SO questions about it, as you can see in the question, but returning false on Touch and Drag events yields no results.